# Unable to generate cucumber.json using Karate

Tags: cucumber, jenkins-pipeline, karate

I'm new to Karate,using version 0.9.4, and I'm triggering my tests from Jenkins pipeline,and Jenkins needs cucumber.json file, to display the results from pipeline. But the problem is I'm not able to get cucumber.json generated. Although all other html reports are properly generated.

The code I'm using :

```
public void testParallel() {
        String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
        Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 5, karateOutputPath);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
    }
```

Could anyone please suggest how to generate cucumber.json ?

Comment: works for me. please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue